# What does cordova prepare do?

Tags: cordova, mobile, cross-platform

I checked the documentation but didn't find a clear explanation about this command.

So does anyone know what exactly does the command `cordova prepare` do?

1. Does it update the platform-specific `www` folders?

   - If yes, does it copy the full content of the root `www`?
2. Does it update the platform-specific icons?

   - If yes, where should the source icons be located?
3. Does it update the platform-specific splash screens?

   - If yes, where should the source splash screens be located?
4. Does it update other platform-specific resources?
5. Does it update the Android manifest?

   - If yes, how can I customize the manifest, so that `cordova prepare` merges both the customization and the generated lines?
6. Which other files are updated for the Android platform?
7. Which other files are updated for the iOS platform?

Answer (score 8):

**Cordova prepare**: It prepares `[<platform> [..]]` by copying the necessary files into the specified platform folder, or for all platform folders. The project is then ready to be built by Eclipse, Xcode, etc.

Refer to: [Cordova Commands](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cordova)

As documentation says:

> In this case, once you run prepare, you can use Apple's Xcode SDK as
>   an alternative to modify and compile the platform-specific code that
>   Cordova generates within platforms/ios. You can use the same approach
>   with other platforms' SDKs.

Refer : [Apache Cordova API Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will ask a more precise question, because I still don't understand how and where add platform-agnostic and platform-specific files...

Comment: Which files are copied? That's exactly the point. I edit the question.

Comment: @jrg : Generally The cordova prepare command copies the content out of your common www to the platform specific directory.

Comment: If you have content in `/merges`, that gets copied to the platform-specific `www` directory as well. Most projects never need to use it, but you should be aware of it.

Comment: It also screws up the `manifest.xml` file overriding that with what Cordova thinks it is best for you!

Comment: Can I copy extra files of my own? How to?

Answer (score 3):

In Cordova 5, a new cool feature has been added to the `cordova prepare` command:

> `<feature>` tags have been renamed to  tags in your projects config.xml. Adding a `<plugin>` tag to your config.xml will fetch and install it on cordova prepare if it isn’t already installed.

http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html